# Imports and requires are not loading properly in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

I am using Vue with Webpack, but I when I import or require another file to be included into my main document, the file seems to have loaded, as in it doesn't give me any errors, but the imports within the files do not load, and I can't use any variables from the files. For example, I have this main document:

```
import './bootstrap';
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

    Vue.use(VueRouter);  


    let Default = Vue.component('Default', {

    template: `
                <li>
                    <a href="#">This is home</a>
                </li>
                `
   });


   let About = Vue.component('About', {

    template: `
                <li>
                    <a href="#">This is about us maaan</a>
                </li>
                `
});



var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Default },
    { path: '/about', component: About }
  ]
}) 

require('./sass/styles.scss');

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  router: router
})
```

...and my bootstrap file is simply:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
```

I get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined`, as if the file had not been included. If I make any changes to the path, I get a file not found error, so I imagine that the file is located. the same for any variables in the file, they are not available in the main file afterwards. This is my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

var inProduction = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: 'dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'images/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },

      {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                fallback: 'style-loader'
            })

      }   
    ]
  },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'styles.css',
            disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        })
  ],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      // sourceMap: true,
      // compress: {
        // warnings: false
      // }
    // }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You aren't exporting anything in your bootstrap file

Comment: Ok, I see that now, but what should I be exporting?